# Using Beautiful soup to pull data from span tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following tags in an HTML document:

```
<span class="availMsg warning product-backorder">Estimated in early March.</span>
```

I am trying to pull the text Estimated in early March text from this span class element but cant seem to make it work.  Here is part of my code I am trying since it contains spaces.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  url = "myWebsite.com"
  html=get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  backordered = soup.find('span').find_all('a', {'class':'availMsg'}).text
  print(backordered)
```

The error I am getting is AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I've tried several variations of soup.find and soup.select but cant seem to get the text I am looking for.  I have other code in my script that pulls from span elements fine for some reason this one is giving me a headache.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Here is an example of one that works:

```
<span class="regPrice">$1,599.00</span>
price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'regPrice'}).text
print(price)
```

The issue has to be with the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns a ResultSet object which you can iterate over using a for loop.

You can iterate through it using the following code:

```
backordered = soup.find('span').find_all('a', {'class':'availMsg'}).text

for i in backordered:
    print(i)
```